# "Живопись делится на докараваджийский период и живопись после Караваджо"?

Tags: согласование, выбор-варианта

"Как есть" мне категорически не нравится.

(И запятые в синодальном переводе, - что с ними делать?)

> И «Савл **встал с земли, и** с открытыми глазами никого не видел. И **повели
>   его за руки, и привели** в Дамаск». Вот как описано это чудо в Библии.
>   Весьма скупо, смею заметить. Революционер света, как принято его
>   называть в учебниках по истории искусства (и действительно – вся
>   мировая живопись делится на **докараваджийский период и живопись после
>   Караваджо**), демонстрирует нам истинное чудо: он выписывает
>   божественный свет – тот самый, что заставил Савла пасть наземь.
>   Караваджо материализует то мгновение, о котором ничего не сказано в
>   Библии.

Если я нарисую:

*...вся мировая живопись делится на до- и послекараваджийский период, -*

это будет очень тяжеловесно?

Периодов два, значит: *до- и послекараваджийский периоды*?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92293/discussion-on-question-by-galina-avanesova----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) ...и действительно – вся мировая живопись делится на **"докараваджийский"** период и живопись после Караваджо. Здесь авторский термин в условных кавычках.

(2)...и действительно, вся мировая живопись делится на  два периода — до и после Караваджо.

Другие варианты по стилю не подходят (выглядят слишком научно).

**Запятые лучше оставить,** они паузу обозначают. По правилам допускается предложения с двумя сказуемыми считать сложными (как бы делить на две ситуации).

Comment: А про периоды где? ***до- и послекараваджийский периоды?***

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас поправим.